# Why getElementById not working on select component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, material-ui, textfield

I have two `TextFields` like this: [image]

One of them is a `Select TextField`. Here is the code:

```
    <TextField
        size="small"
        style = {{width: 700, marginTop: '1rem'}}
        type="text"
        multiline={schema.numberOfLines > 1}
        rows={schema.numberOfLines}
        required
        id="sampleTextField"
        name={schema.name}
        label={schema.display}
        variant="outlined" 
            onChange={(event) => {
           handleDataChange(event.target.name, event.target.value);
        }}>
    </TextField>
    <TextField
        size="small"
        style = {{width: 300, marginTop: '1rem'}}
        required
        id="sampleSelect"
        name={schema.name}
        select
        label={schema.display}
        value={(reportDataObject[schema.name] !== undefined) ? reportDataObject[schema.name] : true }
       onChange={(event) => {
           handleDataChange(event.target.name, event.target.value);
       }}>
       <MenuItem key={true} value={true}>True</MenuItem>
       <MenuItem key={false} value={false}>False</MenuItem>
 </TextField>
```

The issue i am facing is when i call,

```
console.log(document.getElementById("sampleTextField").value);
console.log(document.getElementById("sampleSelect").value);
```

I am getting **sample description**. But, for `Select TextField`, i am getting `undefined`. What could be the reason behind this? Why `document.getElementById` not working on select component?

Comment: What is `TextField`? Is it from [tag:react-material]? If so, please tag it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `mui` library, you could use `Select` component to create select form.

Reference: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/#main-content

P/s: you could try to change the key of `MenuItem` as string.

```
<MenuItem key={'true'} value={true}>
  True
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: i have tried both. Not working,

Comment: What is the purpose of `(reportDataObject[schema.name] !== undefined) ? reportDataObject[schema.name] : true`. If you want to set default value, use defaultValue instead

Comment: chnaged `value` to `defaultValue`. Still not wirking

Comment: THE ULTIMATE SOLUTION: share your source code with me, i need to look around first :D